# 30 items, 75% chance to not consume one. What's the calculation?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics, expected-value

Say I have 30 items and when using, there is a 75% chance to not consume it. What is the effective count of items I have?

How can this be calculated?

---

Edit: This is not a homework question or something. I am just bad at math and I have no clue how this is even called or calculated

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Like when I got 2 items with a 50% chance not to consume, I think I would have effective(?) 3 items. Or 10 items with 10% not to consume it would be 11 items. But I have no clue how this behaves when the percentage goes over 50%. Like 10 items with 90% would not be 19 items but a even greater number. 100% would be infinite.

Comment: What do "consume" and "effective" mean ?

Comment: This is not clear at all.

Comment: consume like, you take one away with an chance to actualy dont take it away. So for example there is a apple basket with 10 apples and when you take one out, the is a 75% chance that another one pops into existing in the basket. And whats the average of apples you got if you take all apples out a million times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define "effective count" as follows:

> If I have $k$ items, and the probability of consuming an item is $p$, then the *effective count* is the number of attempts $n$ to consume an item such that the expected number of items consumed is $k$.

Using statistics notation, let $X$ be the number of consumed items. Then $X \sim \textsf{Binomial}(n, p)$ and its expectation is $E[X] = np$. We want to solve for $n$ given that $E[X]$ is $k$, so we obtain $n = k/p$.

In your example, we have $k = 30$ and $p = 0.25$, so the effective count is $n = 30/0.25 = 120$.

Comment: Thats exactly what I mean.

Comment: It's not immediately clear, but `p = (1 - 0.75) = 0.25`.