# Simplifying chance not to consume formula.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

### Scenario

I have $N$ consumable items with $P$ probability of not being consumed (being preserved and reusable) when used.

On average, how many uses $U$ should I expect before depleting my consumables?

---

### My approximate, brute force solution

JavaScript + NodeJS

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
let precision = 100000000;
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < precision; i++) {
  if (getRandomInt(100000) < 30000)
    // 30% chance
    i--; // not consumed
  sum++;
}
console.log(sum / precision);

// result ~ 1.4285
```

---

### My made-up solution

$U = (N*P^0) + (N*P^1) + (N*P^2) + (N*P^3) + (N*P^4) + (N*P^5)$...etc. (Pattern repeats infintely?)

Example, when $N = 1$ and $P = 0.3$ then $U \approx 1.4285$

---

### [Found solution #1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846441/30-items-75-chance-to-not-consume-one-whats-the-calculation):

$U = \frac{N}{1-P}$

Example, when $N = 1$ and $P = 0.3$ then $U \approx 1.4285$

---

### [Found Solution #2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4100523/how-to-get-an-average-number-of-free-con)

My interpretation:

$P_{p} = P$

$P_{o} = \frac{P_{p}}{(1-P_{p})}$

$U = N + N * P_{o} = N + N * \frac{P_{p}}{1-P_{p}}$

Which ultimately simplifies into the previous solution.

Example, when $N = 1$ and $P = 0.3$ then $U \approx 1.4285$

---

### What I'm trying to do

While I'm an amateur, I'm not looking for an answer to solve a discrete problem, but trying to learn more about the relationship between the problem and solutions presented.  The next thing I want to learn is:

Given $U$ and $P$, what $N$ do I start with so that 66% of the binomial distribution is above $U$ — That is, given $U$ and $P$, what $N$ will give me a 2-in-3 chance of reaching $U$.

However, I want to know more about the current problem and solutions before I move forward.

---

## The Question

Is my made-up solution equivalent to the others?  If so, is there a methodology to convert between them?

Additionally, can I represent the infinite summing of my made-up solution in a more succinct way—without using division?  An approximation is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have N items and, when used, it is removed/depleted with probability $q=1-P$ then, the number of uses you’ll get from a particular item $U_i$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $q$. This means on average, you will get $u=\frac{1}{q}$ uses from any particular item.

The total uses you’ll get for N items is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N U_i$$

By linearity of expectation we’ll have $Nu$ uses on average before you deplete your entire inventory.

Your made up solution is a geometric series and sums to $N+\frac{NP}{1-P}$

So yes, your made up solution is equivalent to the others.

Comment: "Geometric random variable" and "Geometric series" is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @NathanGoings awesome! Be sure to select “accept” I’d this addressed the issues in your question :-)